# Access denied Microsoft.Bcl.Build when switching branch in vs2015 with tfs git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

When switch from branch in vs2015 I got an access denied error

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not remove
 'C:/git/desan.crf/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.14/tools/Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll': 
Access is denied.
```

Closing the project in VS2015 doesn't help.

The problem doesn't exists when I start vs2015 and switch the branch before opening the project

Answer (score 0):

Solved Problem by removing all packages in the `packages` folder from git source control in both branches.

1. Remove the package in the project from the your solution.
2. Check in project.
3. Add an ignore entry to prevent that the folder is committed in the future

Do this for both braches

The problem exists because in only one branch the package was delete

Comment: "removing all packages in the packages folder from git source control", how to do it? remove it in remote repository and add the packages in gitignore?